# MacOS - Find the frontmost process

Tags: c++, macos, process, background-process

I'm writing an C++ application on MacOS and need to be able to determine (ideally using C++) if the application is the frontmost / active process or if its in the background or minimized.

Basically I want to be able to do something like:

```
if(frontProcess()){
    //do some stuff
} else {
    //do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can call `ActiveNonFloatingWindow()` and `FrontNonFloatingWindow()` and see if they are the same.  The first returns the active window, and the second returns your application's frontmost window.

Docs: http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/reference/Window_Manager/wind_mgr_ref/function_group_1.html